# Wordpress: get & store category info

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm wondering: is there any way I can load all the categories and store each one in a different array?

So i've got this code:

```
<?php
$cat_args = array('orderby' => 'name','order' => 'ASC');

$categories = get_categories($cat_args);

foreach($categories as $category) {
    $args = array(
      'showposts'        => -1,
      'category__in'     => array($category->term_id),
      'caller_get_posts' => 1
    );

    $posts = get_posts($args);

    if ($posts) {
        echo '<p>Category: <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </p> ';

        foreach($posts as $post) {
          setup_postdata($post);
          ?> <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p> <?php
        } // foreach($posts
    } // if ($posts
} // foreach($categories
?>
```

I want to make it so that I can use it later like that (outside the loop):

```
<?php echo $category[0] -> name . $category[1] -> name . $category[2] -> name; ?>
```

Comment: Please note: `caller_get_posts` and `showposts` has been depreciated a couple of years ago. They where replaced by `ignore_sticky_posts` and `posts_per_page` respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need an array of category names, you can alter your code as follows; (*PLEASE NOTE:`caller_get_posts` and `showposts` has been depreciated a couple of years ago. They where replaced by `ignore_sticky_posts` and `posts_per_page` respectively*)

```
<?php
$cat_args = array('orderby' => 'name','order' => 'ASC');

$categories = get_categories($cat_args);

$category_names = array();
foreach($categories as $category) {
    $category_names[] = $category->name;
    $args = array(
      'posts_per_page'        => -1,
      'category__in'     => array($category->term_id),
      'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
    );

    $posts = get_posts($args);

    if ($posts) {
        echo '<p>Category: <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </p> ';

        foreach($posts as $post) {
          setup_postdata($post);
          ?> <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p> <?php
        } // foreach($posts
    } // if ($posts
} // foreach($categories
?>
```

`$category_names` will now hold an array of category names.

If you need to display a list of categories with posts below them, you should check out [my post here on WPSE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/145960/31545). Your method is very resource intensive and slow. My method is superfast, use transients, and at optimum does only 2 db queries in under 0.002 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Note: You already have the data in this format in $categories variable.
So you can use anywhere like this

```
<?php echo $categories[0] -> name . $categories[1] -> name . $categories[2] -> name; ?>
```